# Elasticsearch match_all returns only one result

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have  logstash setup to send output to elastisearch:

```
output {

    stdout { codec => rubydebug}

    elasticsearch_http {
        host => "localhost"
        index => "logstash-systest-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        document_id => 1
        index_type => "systemtest"

        }
}
```

The log file has  many rows of data in it, and stdout shows that all those rows are being parsed and formatted. However when I query elasticsearch with a match_all query the only result returned is the data from the last row of the log file.

```
POST  /logstash-systest-2014.10.06/_search

{

        "query": {"match_all": {}}
 }
```

Any ideas why only the last row of data is being returned? I have restarted elasticsearch and logstash and deleted the sincedb, still the same result.

Comment: I don't know how your query DSL is working. I think  `"query": {"match_all": {}}})` should be `"query": { "match_all": {}}`

Comment: Thanks.Error while posting the question.I just edited it. I get only the last row of the log file using match_all.

Comment: Can you show last few record log? It might be  your `document_id` is same for all the documents. When you trying to index data its overwriting previous records. So its obvious it will display last inserted record.

Comment: Not related but you can also run `GET /logstash-systest-2014.10.06/_search` without any JSON. It will run a match_all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you set the document id. So each line has the same id. which means that each line is erased by the next one.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I am trying to get the python elasticsearch client talk to elasticsearch and one of the functions elasticsearch.exists() needed a document id, so had to set it in the config file. Any idea how to get a list of existing document id's from elasticsearch?

Comment: Not sure I understood what you are trying to achieve. May be you should open a new question with all details?